# Django: do not allow users to see pages when they are not logged in

Tags: python, django, login-required

I created a very basic login application. The LOGIN_URL, LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL and the LOGOUT_URL work just fine.

The thing is that if i log in succesully and then i close the window (browser) and then i reopen the browser, i can perfectly search the url (the one i am supose to only see if i am logged in) and use the applcation without loggin in again. This is not where it ends: if i open 2 separate browsers: Chrome and Firefox at the same time and i only logged in in ONE, i can use the applicaction from the other browser without problems.
I dont want this to happend. I tried using login_required in the urls.conf for the index view (the page that you can only see if you are logged in) and in the class view, i tried using stronhold, and django-braces. Is ther any other way to do this?. If you want to see any of the code let me know. Im using the login and log out that django implements (auth).
Than you

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post but maybe the answer will help others in the future.
if you workflow is class based views you have to use: **LoginRequiredMixin**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views import generic

class CreateGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    fields = ('name', 'description')
    model = Group
```

**The LoginRequired mixin**

When using class-based views, you can archive the same behavior as with login_required by using the LoginRequiredMixin. This mixin should be at the leftmost position in the inheritance list.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/

Answer (score 2):

It would seem like you need to wrap the 'private' views with Django's [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

This will redirect to `LOGIN_URL` if the user is not logged in or authenticated.

Comment: I already tried to di this with no success. I have this done in my code already, but it seems that is not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: And i´m using class based views so i think its a different sintax, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

in the view to the which your login redirects you can add:

```
def after_login(request,..):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        redirect('some-non-existence-page-or-404',...)
    #Your code
    return
```